# behaviour of const static qualifier

Tags: c, static, constants

when i am trying to build this program it is giving warning as,

> initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

But when i am executing it is giving output as

```
    p and (&sa) has same addresses
    but *p and sa has different values
```

I am confused why is it giving different values.

```
#include<stdio.h>

const static int sa;

int main (void)
{
    int *p = &sa;

    *p = 32;

    printf("*p : %d\tp = %p\n", *p, p);
    printf("sa : %d\t&sa = %p\n", sa, &sa); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What behaviour do you expect by assigning a value to a **const** variable?

Comment: if i assign a value to 'sa' it will be in rodata so when i try to change it will give segfault

Comment: Actually, this is undefined behaviour.